# Keytool generates 32 character long key hash instead of 28

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I am using the following command to generate key hash for Facebook app console for Android

```
.\keytool.exe -exportcert -alias app_android -keystore release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

As told at [Facebook developers SDK help](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)

As per the help page and also the developers console, the key hash should be 28 characters long, however the keytool is generating 32 characters long key.

Java version : jdk1.8.0_31
OS : Windows 7

Generating for android.

EDIT

As per suggestion from @Shreyash-mashru, I used the following code to get the keyhash

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "my.package.name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + e.toString());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + e.toString());
    }
```

However if someone can still help me out understand why the command line tool is generating 32 char long key hash instead of 28...

Comment: Suggestion. Its easy to use that method which you can find from above link which you have posted and you can just get hash it into your logs. and Copy and paste from it to your facebook app.[link of that page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks @shreyashmashru will try that. But any idea why the keytool generates 32 chars instead of 28?

Comment: Thank you for this question.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Came across this problem too, for me I was using windows powershell and it kept generating a 32 character key. When I switch to plain old cmd it worked as expected.

Comment: Thats interesting... I was using powershell as well. Will check this out definitely when someday I am back to windows.

Comment: same with me, though it was not generating 32 char long but it was showing invalid by Facebook (gving error : it should be = at the end like that), used cmd and worked perfectly

Comment: Well this solutions worked perfectly for my particular problem.

Comment: Same here. I wonder if that is an openSSL issue or a power shell thing.

Comment: It solves the issue. For those who is wondering which openssl zip/rar is suitable, I can confirm that openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip at https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads is working as expected for 64-bit clients.

Comment: you are my hero. Note: I did it with OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021

Comment: Man you are my personal Hero!

Comment: This is quite interested, found myself in a similar situation, but as for me I had to use cmder, some open-source command-line tool for windows

Comment: Ohh, thank you man. I was using power shell. when swich to cmd It works like charm.

Comment: @hanilozmen thx bro!

Answer (score 5):

The generated hash is 32 characters because there is a carriage return and a newline added to the end. To fix this you can either:

Delete the last 5 characters of the hash, and add an `"="` to the end. For example: `"1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"` (32 chars) --> `"1234567890abcdefghijklmnopq="` (28 chars)

**Or:**

pop open a javascript console, and use:

```
btoa(atob("your hash string").slice(0, -2))
```

Where `"your hash string"` is your 32 character hash.

Answer (score 2):

try normal cmd prompt or use git bash command prompt it will generate 28 characters long string. do not use Windows PowerShell cause it generates 32 characters long string.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THE COMMAND IN COMMAND PROMPT !**

it will ask you for password then you will get the **hash key**

Trying the same command on **powershell** doesn't provide correct hash key.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It had something to do with using my existing version of openSSL (64 bit). I downloaded the 32 bit version [from here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads) and installed it to c:\openSSL. The command then points to this version of SSL and I got my 28 character hash.

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   "C:\Users\USERNAME.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl"
>   sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then open cmd and enter the below command

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Running this in any

Answer (score -4):

```
.\keytool.exe -exportcert -alias app_android -keystore release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

this is working fine for me. try it again.

Comment: Is the hash 28 char long? Can you mention the environment and java version?

Comment: yes,Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)

Comment: I think the issue is related to the usage of Powershell instead of Command Prompt. So, rerunning the command will not solve it.