# Getting hash key of 20 character instead 28 for facebook integration with android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am integrating my android app with facebook . i am following  [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) link but  i am getting 20 character hashkey  so it makes trouble . I am using following command on cmd

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\mahi\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

[image]

Comment: how you solved the problem??

Answer (score 12):

Instetad of SHA1, type SHA. You will get 28 char long hashcode for fb. I was having the same issue, but this way I could resolved.

Comment: I got a different hash by SHA. but still length 20 :\

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Windows Powershell and it is generating a 24-length key. Switched back to old cmd. Thanks to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677624/9376804